# Can hiragana & katakana "spell" the sounds of all Japonic, etc. topolects?

Tags: dialects

Japan has a lot of topolects. Most of them are all classified under Japonic. These include Ryukyuan, Hachijō, Kyūshū and obviously eastern and western Japanese.

Can hiragana & katakana "spell" the sounds of all Japonic, etc. topolects?

Are there sounds and pronunciations outside of general hiragana & katakana abilities?

Answer (score 8):

At least Okinawan has nonstandard kana to precisely represent their sounds. For example, Okinawan has two types of う ([u] and [ʔu]), whose difference is important for the local people to distinguish their native words.

- [Does Okinawan have syllables Japanese doesn't?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43775/5010)
- [Okinawan scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okinawan_scripts)

Ainu also has [special katakana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainu_language#Special_katakana_for_the_Ainu_language), although Ainu may not be Japonic.

There is always a way to approximate their words only using standard kana, anyway.

To the best of my knowledge, in dialects in Honshu/Shikoku/Kyushu, no special kana is used. Of course there are regional varieties only describable with IPA (e.g., [う is nearer to [u] than to [ɯ] in Kansai dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansai_dialect#Phonology)) or allophones found only in some dialects (e.g., [yotsugana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yotsugana) and [bidakuon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakuten_and_handakuten#Phonetic_shifts)), but they are not distinguishing features. (Bidakuon have special characters, but they are more like phonetic symbols to me.)

Comment: Adding to your answer: For Kyushu dialects there are some remnant sounds from old Japanese, but they can be written using extended Kana: [くゎ], [せ]→[しぇ], [え]→[いぇ] etc. These are however rarely used among youngsters

Comment: This is a tangent, but I'd even argue that が has at least two allophones in dialects in Japan. Apart from the standard /ga/ , I've definitely heard a /nga/ sound many times, which is more like the nasal velar consonant ŋ

Comment: @kandyman I heard broadcasters were trained to pronounce n + が行 for aesthetic reason 50 years ago. Now they pronounce normal が行.

Comment: @kimiTanaka that's interesting. I wonder why they changed.

Comment: `...50 years ago. Now they pronounce normal が行`  [鼻濁音]{びだくおん}をきちんと発音する一般人は関東でも減ってますが、アナウンサー（特にNHKの）は現在でも正しく発音するように言われていると思うんですが。。。真面目なニュースのアナウンス聞いてたら、格助詞の「が」とかちゃんと鼻濁音で読まれてますよね。